# Creating a one query list

Tags: sql, oracle

List a count of the number of employees who work in either department 10 or 20, the average, minimum, and maximum employee salary in these departments, and a total of all their salaries combined (This question must be done by using one query)

MY CODE:

```
SELECT DEPTNO, AVG(SAL), MAX(SAL), MIN(SAL), SUM(SAL) AS TOTAL_SAL 
FROM EMP 
WHERE DEPTNO = 10 OR DEPTNO=20 
GROUP BY DEPTNO;
```

Table Schema:

[image: EMP table]

Comment: What did you do so far? What issue are you facing?

Comment: SELECT DEPTNO, AVG(SAL), MAX(SAL), MIN(SAL), SUM(SAL) AS TOTAL_SAL FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO = 10 OR DEPTNO=20 GROUP BY DEPTNO;

Comment: Ok. Then you should update your question to also include this code.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  You will want to use a "group by"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a:

count(DEPTNO) as NumberEmployeesInDept

to your select and I think you will be done.